# Error reading response length from authentication socket

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3

In my ruby on rails project, I am using capistrano , unicorn, postgresql and nginx for deploying my project. when I run `cap production git:check`  I am getting this error:

```
Error reading response length from authentication socket.
```

log trace:

```
INFO [13522bc0] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/deploy_test/ as mezbah@192.168.137.130
DEBUG [13522bc0] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/deploy_test/
INFO [13522bc0] Finished in 0.291 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG Uploading /tmp/deploy_test/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
INFO Uploading /tmp/deploy_test/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
INFO [3b379ef0] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/deploy_test/git-ssh.sh as mezbah@192.168.137.130
DEBUG [3b379ef0] Command: /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/deploy_test/git-ssh.sh
INFO [3b379ef0] Finished in 0.067 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [8355617a] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@github.com:mezbahalam/deploy_test.git as mezbah@192.168.137.130
DEBUG [8355617a] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/deploy_test/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@github.com:mezbahalam/deploy_test.git )
DEBUG [8355617a]    Error reading response length from authentication socket.
DEBUG [8355617a]    6399a4a331342141ed3bbf3afb58f58828f96c76    refs/heads/master
INFO [8355617a] Finished in 9.683 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

I read some [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123896/capistrano-deployment-from-windows-using-forward-agent-option-error-reading-re) but I can't figureout any solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**TL;DR**

```
# start/restart ssh-agent
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"

# add the desired ssh-key
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

See: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/ for more details.

---

I went through the same issue in the past and this post helped me a lot to fix it:
http://www.antleon.com/2014/04/rails-capistrano-deployment-ssh-error-reading-response-length-from-authentication-socket/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why this occurs, but I've seen it on a number of my deploys and they continue to work perfectly. I think this error can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

When this happened to me, it was because the ssh-agent wasn't running anymore. I restarted it and checked there was a key listed when I ran `ssh-add -L`